# How to subscribe for value changes on an input from a different module in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular6

I have a header component that is located in the root (app) module. A search bar would be rendered in the header depending on the activated route.

I have *friends* lazy loaded module with a *friends-list* container component that provides a list of friends.

I want to add a search functionality to the *friends-list* component by subscribing to value changes on the search bar input.

How can I provide the observable of the search bar value changes to my friends-list component?

Comment: You can use a shared service to emit the searchInputChange event to `friend-list` component.

Comment: I thought of this but how would I put the value changes observable in the service?

Comment: Yes you can add a `Subject` variable inside service and then emit it from the shared service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make usage of `shared` service to emit the event from `search bar` component to `friends-list` component.

Create a `Subject` inside service, and then emit whenever the input is changed.

service.ts

```
public searchInputChanged : Subject<string> = new Subject<string>()

emitSearchInputChangesEvent(input) {
   this.searchInputChanged.next(input);
}
```

search-bar component :
Simply call the method `emitSearchInputChangesEvent(input)`

```
public onChange (event) {
   this.service.emitSearchInputChangesEvent(event);
}
```

in friend-list component, subscribe to `Subject` event emitter of service.

```
this.service.searchInputChanged.subscribe((input)=> {
     console.log(input):
})
```

Comment: Yeap, works pretty well. Could you please add that in order for a service to be shared it has to have @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) decorator? Just to make sure that everyone would get this correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it as `@Input` to your lazy loaded component or expose input changes trough shared service

Comment: `@Input` wont work if the two components are not parent-child.

Comment: And did OP specified how it is in his case? No. Did I use alternative with `OR` keyword? Yes.